# How do I alert in Stackdriver based on App Engine spending limits?

Tags: google-app-engine, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Is there a way to alert in StackDriver -- or in some other way programmatically -- when my app gets to 80% of [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/#setting_a_spending_limit) spending limits that we have defined?

I am aware of budget alerts, but these may include expenses beyond Standard Environment, and so are not aligned with my needs: I am looking for a warning for system administrators that the system might stop, rather than the financial warning that billing alerts are designed for.

Answer (score 0):

By default setting a budget does not cap resource or API consumption. Therefore, raising a warning or an alert does not impact your project unless your payment has been declined.

You can take advantage of Cloud Billing Budget API[1] option for sending an email alert to Billing Account Administrators and Billing Account Users about your actual billing state.

To manage alerts programmatically, You can review provided link[2]

If the above solutions are not addressing your request fully please feel free to open a feature request with GCP support team with details about the feature that you would like to have.[3]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budget-api

[2] https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets?_ga=2.112369478.-33739448#manage-notifications

[3] https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: (1) This is not Budgets,this is Spending Limits in GAE, the one place in GCP that does block the app when the limit is reached. (2)  the Budget API won't do it, because GAE Spending Limits only apply to very specific services in the context of GAE, not well-aligned with overall GCP billing.,

Comment: Also (3) Budget alerts are monthly and GAE hard spending limits are daily